# Cannot upload large files using multiple file upload window

Tags: document-library

In SharePoint 2010, using IE 9, and with Office 2010 32bit installed on the client PC, I cannot upload multiple files to a SharePoit library using the "Upload Multiple Documents..." control if the files are larger than 100MB.

I have the max file size set to 2GB in SharePoint and IIS.

I can upload the files one at a time if I browse to them. I cannot upload the files one at a time if I drag and drop into the "Upload Multiple Documents..." window.  The control shows a red icon and "Failed" but I cannot find any errors in the logs.

What is going on here?  How can I upload multiple large files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. This is a safeguard placed by SP when you use the multiple file upload interface.

Your other options are to use:

- The Explorer View, or
- The SP object model (few lines of code).

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean a limit of 100 *files*, not MB?

Comment: Found issue: 1) to long filename, 2) special characters in filename, 3) emails with attachments which are blocked